# Auto Copy To Clipboard Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript

I have a flash app that I want to auto copy a string of text to the clipboard.

what i have now works locally but when i put it on my server it doesn't work.

this is what i have

```
System.setClipboard("testing testing 123");
```

Anyone got any idea what could be the problem? im guessing its some sort of security feature but what im using it for is whitehat.

Answer (score 2):

looks like with FP10 adobe changed their security settings, so that the clipboard can only be set after an user interaction:

http://blog.andrewng.com/2008/10/21/flash-10-security-changes-setclipboard-requires-user-interaction/